Trying to flatten a json field, but same syntax only works for some fields in the same depth
I wrote a query in dbt connected to Redshift db to flatten a json field, but for some reason, only cohort, message, and event_properties fields are populated in the output,  campaign_name and email_subject fields are null. I am sure the fields are not null since event_properties field has content in this particular entry.
Is there something that is done incorrectly here? These fields are in the same depth so I am unable to find a reason why only some of them are returning value.
SELECT 
        flow_document.attributes.event_properties."$_cohort$message_send_cohort" as cohort,    
        flow_document.attributes.event_properties."$message" as message,
        flow_document.attributes.event_properties as event_properties,    
        flow_document.attributes.event_properties."Campaign Name" as campaign_name,
        flow_document.attributes.event_properties."Subject" as email_subject
FROM {{ ref('events') }}

The content of event_properties for reference:
{

"cohort": "cohort123",
"$event_id": "event234",
"$message": "message123",
"Campaign Name": "campaign123",
"Email Domain": "gmail.com",
"Inbox Provider": "Gmail",
"Subject": "Check this subject out"
}

I have tried casting the null fields into different data types checked that the fields match the record provided.

It is the upper case letters in the key names. Redshift by default is case insensitive (translates to lower case) and when dealing with super keys it translates everything to lower case.
Try turning on case sensitivity:
SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;

However, this enables case sensitivity for all table and column references so you may need to modify some queries or turn this option on and off only around that queries that need case sensitivity.

Yes, thank you for this answer, it worked!
